# How to fix incorrect number of width of an element that accessed using JavaScript bundled with Webpack v. 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

This is my first time using Webpack and Babel, but I got little bit problem that I can't solve it by my self cause I've ran out of ideas. When I was trying to log the width of an element, the result that showed was incorrect. That's happened when I logged through Webpack, but when I logged through developer console directly in browser, it showed the correct result. For example, I try to log the width of sidebar element which is 270px, but when I log it through Webpack to the console it gives me 1366px.

I don't know why it could be happened. But I was guessing that the problem is in Webpack, so I try to change the Babel into the latest version. But it still didn't works. Is there anyone can help me to fix that? Thank you for your attention and Sorry for mediocre english.

Below is my Webpack code, just for your information

```
const path = require('path')
const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV
const MiniCSSExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode,
  entry: ['./resources/scripts/main.js', './resources/sass/main.sass'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/public'
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCSSExtractPlugin({
      filename: mode == 'production' ? '[name].[hash].css' : '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: mode == 'production' ? '[id].[hash].css' : '[id].css'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|c|sc)ss$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: [
          mode == 'production' ? MiniCSSExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```